# Is there a listing of known whois query output formats?

Tags: parsing, format, whois

**TL;DR:** I need a source for as many different output formats from a whois query as possible.

**Background:**

- I am looking for a single reference that can provide as many (if not all) unique whois query output formats as possible.

  - I don't believe this exists but hope to be proven wrong.
- This appears to be an age old problem

  - [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653098/automatic-whois-data-parsing) from 2015 references the challenge of handling the "~40 formats" that the author was aware of.

    - The author never detailed any of these formats.
  - The [RFC for whois](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912) is... depressing
  - The [IETF ran an analysis in 2015](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7485) that examined the components of whois per each RIR at the time

    - In my own research I see that registrars like JPNIC do not appear to comply with the APNIC standards

I am aware of existing tools that do a bang-up job parsing whois ([python-whois](https://github.com/joepie91/python-whois) for example) however I'd like to hedge my bets against outliers with odd formats. I'm also open to possible approaches to gather this information, however that would likely be too broad to fit this question.

Hoping there is a simple "go here and download this" answer. Hoping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TL;DR: I need a source for as many different output formats from a whois query as possible."

There isn't, except if you use any kind of provider that does this for you, with whatever caveats.
Or more precisely there isn't something public, maintained and exhaustive. You can find various libraries that try to do this, in various languages, but none is complete, as this is basically an impossible task, especially if you want to include any TLDs, like ccTLDs (you are not framing your constraints space in a very detailed way, nor in fact really saying you are asking about domain name data in whois or IP addresses/ASN data?).

Some providers of course try to do that and offering you an abstract uniform API. But why would anyone share their internal secret sauce, that is list of parsers and so on? It makes no business incentive to do that.
As for opensource library authors (I was one at some point), it is just tedious and absolutely not rewarding at all to just update it forever with all new formats and tweaks per registry (battle scar example: one registrar in the past changed its output format at each query! one query gave you `somefield: somevalue` while next time it was `somefield:somevalue` or `somefield somevalue`, etc. of course that is only a simple example).

RFC 3912 specified just the transport part, not the content, hence a lot of cases appeared. Specifically in the ccTLD world, each registry is king in its kingdom and it is free to implement whatever it wants the way it wants. Also the protocol had some serious limitations (ex: internationalization, what is the "charset" used for the underlying data) that were circumvented in different ways (like passing "options" in your query... of course none of them are standardized in any way)

At the very least, gTLDs whois format is specified there:
https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois

Note however that due to GDPR there were changes (see https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/gtld-registration-data-specs-en/#temp-spec) and will be other changes in the future.

However, you should be highly pressed to look at RDAP instead of whois.

RDAP is now a requirement in all gTLDs registries and registries. As it is JSON, it solves immediately the problem of format.

Its core specifications are:

- [RFC 7480 HTTP Usage in the Registration Data Access Protocol (RDAP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7480)
- [RFC 7481 Security Services for the Registration Data Access Protocol (RDAP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7481)
- [RFC 7482 Registration Data Access Protocol (RDAP) Query Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7482)
- [RFC 7483 JSON Responses for the Registration Data Access Protocol (RDAP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7483)
- [RFC 7484 Finding the Authoritative Registration Data (RDAP) Service](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7484)

You can find various libraries doing RDAP for you (see below for links), but at its core it is JSON over HTTPS so you can emulate simple cases with any kind of HTTP client library.

Work is underway to fix some missing/not precise enough details on RFC 7482 and 7483.

You need also to take into account ICANN specifications (again, only for gTLDs of course):

- https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/rdap-technical-implementation-guide-15feb19-en.pdf
- https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/rdap-response-profile-15feb19-en.pdf

Note that, right now, even if it is an ICANN requirement, you will find a lot of missing or broken gTLD registries or registrar RDAP server. You will also find a lot of "deviations" in replies from what would be expected per the specification.

I gave full details in various other questions here, so maybe have a look:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877920/6368697
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066735/6368697
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/115605/75842
- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213854/137710
- https://serverfault.com/a/999095/396475

PS: philosophical question on "Hoping there is a simple "go here and download this" answer. Hoping..." because a lot of people hoped for that in the past, and see initial remark at beginning. Let us imagine you go forward and build this magnificent resource with all exhaustive details. Would you be inclined to just share it with anyone, for free? The answer is probably no, for obvious reasons, so the same happened in the past for others that went on the same path as you, and hence the results of now various providers offering you more or less this service (you would need to find details on which formats are parsed, the rate limites, the prices, etc.), but nothing freely available to share.

Now you can just dream/hope that every registries and registrars switch to RDAP **AND** implement it properly. Then the problem of format is solved once for all. However, the above requirements ("every" + "properly") are not small, and may not happen "soon".  Specifically in ccTLDs, where registries are in no way mandated by any external force (except market pressure?) to implement RDAP at all.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Your response is *incredibly* thorough and useful. I'm confident that it will help others as well. I can't believe I didn't know about RDAP; at this time I am mostly concerned with .com. The ccTLDs may be a consideration in the future, however this is likely to address my concerns for now. Appreciate you sharing your knowledge!